# Алгоритм сортировочной станции Дейкстры, проблема с двузначными числами

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

stack<char> st;
stack<int> stlet;
int a, b, k = 0, i, n;

void st_oper(char s);
bool isNumber(char Symbol);
int main()
{
    string s;
    string s1;
    cout << "Enter The String For Reverse Polish Notation" << endl;
    getline(cin, s);

    for (i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        k = i;
        n = 0;

        if (s[i] == '*')
        {
            while (st.size())
            {
                if (st.top() == '+' || st.top() == '-' || st.top() == '(')break;

                st_oper(st.top());
            }

            st.push(s[i]);
        }
        else if (s[i] == '/')
        {
            while (st.size())
            {
                if (st.top() == '+' || st.top() == '-' || st.top() == '(')break;

                st_oper(st.top());
            }

            st.push(s[i]);
        }
        else  if (s[i] == '+')
        {
            while (st.size())
            {
                if (st.top() == '(')break;

                st_oper(st.top());
            }

            st.push(s[i]);
        }
        else   if (s[i] == '-')
        {
            while (st.size())
            {
                if (st.top() == '(')break;

                st_oper(st.top());
            }

            st.push(s[i]);
        }
        else if (s[i] == '(')
        {
            st.push(s[i]);
        }
        else if (s[i] == ')')
        {
            while (st.size())
            {
                if (st.top() == '(')
                {
                    st.pop();
                    break;
                }

                st_oper(st.top());
            }
        }
        else if (isNumber(s[i]))
        {
            while (isNumber(s[k]))
            {
                if (k == s.size())break;

                s1[n] = s[k];
                n++;
                k++;
            }

            k--;
            i = k;
            stlet.push(atoi(s1.c_str()));
        }

        //считывает посимвольно
    }

    while (st.size())st_oper(st.top());

    cout << stlet.top();
}
void st_oper(char s)
{
    if (stlet.size() > 1)
    {
        a = stlet.top();
        stlet.pop();
        b = stlet.top();
        stlet.pop();

        if (s == '+')
        {
            b += a;
            st.pop();
            stlet.push(b);
        }
        else if (s == '-')
        {
            b -= a;
            st.pop();
            stlet.push(b);
        }
        else  if (s == '*')
        {
            b *= a;
            st.pop();
            stlet.push(b);
        }
        else  if (s == '/')
        {
            b /= a;
            st.pop();
            stlet.push(b);
        }
    }
}

bool isNumber(char Symbol)
{
    if (Symbol >= '0' && Symbol <= '9')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

С однозначными числами все прекрасно работает, но с двузначными - выводит не то, уже пару часов туплю, не подскажете ошибку?

Comment: ну и форматирование кода... А отладчиком пробовали смотреть что не так?

Comment: @pavel, что-то не особо лучше стало :-)

Comment: а что происходит в этом блоке? `if(isNumber(s[i]))
    {
        while(isNumber(s[k]))
    {
    if(k==s.size())break;s1[n]=s[k];n++;k++;
    }
    k--;i=k;stlet.push(atoi(s1.c_str()));
    }`?

Comment: если символ - от '0' до '9', т.е - цифра, то пока не встретиться +-*/, будем идти вперед по строке и вписывать по одной цифре в строку s1, как только встретили НЕ цифру - вышли, преобразовали полученное число в integer и запихнули в стек.(вот в этой строке и где-то проблема)

Comment: Честно говоря, отладчиком пользуюсь не особо умело, поэтому не решался проверить.

Comment: Делайте тогда отладочный вывод, если отладчика боитесь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, `isNumber` замените библиотечной `isdigit`, а во-вторых, перепишите "ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи" (с), например, так:

```
else if (isdigit(s[i]))
{
    int val = 0;
    while (isdigit(s[i]))
    {
        val = val*10 + (s[i] - '0');
        ++i;
    }
    --i;
    stlet.push(val);
}
```

Comment: Фух, спасибо за решение, я много мучился)

Comment: Ну, если оно вас устраивает - нажимайте "птичку" слева от ответа.